# always serializer is invalid

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

### models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
   state = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
   # . . . other fields
```

### views.py

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1)

serializer = LenderProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data)

if serializer.is_valid():
     serializer.save()
```

### serializers.py

```
class LenderProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

        fields = [
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'city',
            'state'
          ]
```

This is my code. For example, I am trying to fill only some fields and so I gave `serializer = LenderProfileSerializer(profile, data=request.data)` still it is giving invalid.

Comment: What is inside of `serializer.errors`?..

Comment: in my code there  is no serializer.errors

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't have an invalid serializer without there being any errors

Comment: ya,i didn't gave null=True for some fields in my table...thank you @Sayse for trying to help me